# RSS Publishing Tool

Tags: looking-for-a-script, rss

Are there any good tools for publishing and maintaining an RSS feed for my site? 
I want to have nice way to create a compliant feeds. Ideally I would be able to have multiple people maintain the feed but that might be asking a lot.

Comment: Are you using any kind of content management system? How do you publish web content?

Comment: I am not using  any cms. I upload files by hand using secure ftp so there is not way to automatically generate the feed.

Comment: Are you able to create a bash script to automatically generate the feed? RSS is not really something one would normally handcode.

Comment: @Ciaran Well, then I would be coding a bash script by hand to avoid coding a RSS feed by hand. I was hoping to find a solid application to do it for me.

Comment: The difference is, you only need to code the bash script once, whereas you'd have to edit the RSS feed by hand every single time. But this is the same reason most people just use a CMS. The CMS can store structured data so that it can generate RSS/Atom/HTML/PDF and any other format you want to automatically any time your content is changed.

Answer (score 2):

have you tied http://feedburner.google.com/ this is a great tool for managing RSS and even iTunes podcast feeds

Comment: I like the looks of feedburner but I don't seem to be able to actually publish content from the site.

Comment: you can use any blogging platform you like. feedburner can help you manager your feeds.

Comment: Feedburner doesn't actually generate RSS feeds. It just reads them and then republishes them at a new location with analytics tracking and provides cross-device/format support.

Answer (score 2):

Try getting a [wordpress.com](http://www.wordpress.com/) blog. They will create a rss feed of your posts for you, and you can manage a rss feed that way. In addition, you can [generate a rss feed of a twitter account](http://seo-alien.com/tips-and-tricks/find-twitter-rss-feed/).

Answer (score 2):

[ListGarden RSS Feed Generator](http://www.softwaregarden.com/products/listgarden/)

Runs locally in Perl, free and licensed under the GPL.